# How to perform ALTER DATABASE within a TRANSACTION In SqlServer

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions

I am doing some work on a remote sql server database which take some time and i need to block any other connection to it so no data get lost 
i believe i should use single user mode  to do this

i need to get it back to multi user mode after i finish my work but
my connection to the remote sever is not reliable and many times will get disconnected before finish and usually just roll back automatically and do it later 
the problem is when i try to perform it within transaction  i get this error :

**ALTER DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction**

how can i perform

```
ALTER DATABASE dbName
SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

in a transaction and make sure it will roll back to Multi user mode if got disconnected ?

Comment: Asking how to be able to do *exactly* the thing the error has told you isn't possible doesn't seem very sensible. There may be other strategies that are viable here, if your actual aim is what you state at the end - get the database back into multi-user mode as some form of failsafe. (e.g. set up a job with an appropriate schedule to change the database back before commencing your work)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i am obviously looking for a work around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, we're trying to arrange for a database to be returned to multi_user mode if our connection drops. Here's one way that *works*, but is as ugly as sin.

First, we set things up appropriately:

```
create database RevertTest
go
use master
go
create table RevertLock (L int not null)
go
declare @rc int
declare @job_id uniqueidentifier

exec @rc = msdb..sp_add_job @job_name='RevertSingleUser',
                            @description='Revert the RevertTest database to multi_user mode',
                            @delete_level=3,
                            @job_id = @job_id OUTPUT

if @rc != 0 goto Failed

exec @rc = msdb..sp_add_jobstep @job_id = @job_id,
                                @step_name = 'Wait to revert',
                                @command = '
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM RevertLock)
    WAITFOR DELAY ''00:00:01''

ALTER DATABASE RevertTest set multi_user

DROP TABLE RevertLock'
if @rc != 0 goto Failed

declare @nowish datetime
declare @StartDate int
declare @StartTime int

set @nowish = DATEADD(minute,30,GETDATE())
select @StartDate = DATEPART(year,@nowish) * 10000 + DATEPART(month,@nowish) * 100 + DATEPART(day,@nowish),
        @StartTime = DATEPART(hour,@nowish) * 10000 + DATEPART(minute,@nowish) * 100 + DATEPART(second,@nowish)

exec @rc = msdb..sp_add_jobschedule @job_id = @job_id,
                                    @name='Failsafe',
                                    @freq_type=1,
                                    @active_start_date = @StartDate,
                                    @active_start_time = @StartTime
if @rc != 0 goto Failed

exec @rc = msdb..sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @job_id
if @rc != 0 goto Failed

print 'Good to go!'
goto Fin
Failed:
print 'No good - couldn''t establish rollback plan'
Fin:
```

Basically, we create a job that tidies up after us. We schedule the job to start running in half an hours time, but that's just to protect us from a small race.

We now run our actual script to do the work that we want it to:

```
use RevertTest
go
alter database RevertTest set single_user with rollback immediate
go
begin transaction
go
insert into master..RevertLock(L) values (1)
go
exec msdb..sp_start_job @job_name='RevertSingleUser'
go
WAITFOR DELAY '01:00:00'
```

If you run this script, you'll be able to observe that the database has entered single-user mode - the `WAITFOR DELAY` at the end is just to simulate us "doing work" - whatever it is that you want to do within the database whilst it's in single-user mode. If you stop this query running *and* disconnect this query window, within a second you should see that the database has returned to `multi_user` mode.

To finish your script successfully, just make the last task (before `COMMIT`) to be to delete from the `RevertLock` table. Just as with the disconnection, the revert job<sup>1</sup> will take care of switching the DB back into `multi_user` and then cleaning up after itself.

---

<sup>1</sup>The job is actually slightly deceptive. It won't actually sit looping and checking the table in master - since your transaction has an exclusive lock on it due to the `INSERT`. It instead sits and patiently waits to acquire a suitable lock, which only happens when your transaction commits or rolls back.

Comment: thank you for your effort , it is a great answer although i still can not use it because i am working with sql express . so there is no jobs

Comment: if there is not any other answer , this should be considered as the right answer

Comment: @M.Sabaa - yes, sorry there's not an easy way when it comes to Express. The nature of this answer is "get code running in an independent context" - and there's no straightforward way to do that with Express. I have occasionally done "sort-of" jobs by installing start-up procedures that don't terminate and just wait until the right time of day to do work - but that needs you to be able to restart the service and it's not really suitable for the task at hand here.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot include the ALTER statement within your transaction.  But you could top and tail your transaction, like so:

```
ALTER DATABASE TEST SET SINGLE_USER 
GO

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

        -- Generate an error.
        SELECT 1/0


    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

GO
ALTER DATABASE TEST SET MULTI_USER
```

This script sets the db to single user mode.  Then encounters an error, before returning to multi user mode.

Comment: what about when my connection to the server became disconnected ,

Comment: I'd suggest looking at Damien_The_Unbeliever's answer.